# Flutter and AWS Amplify user Auth

Tags: flutter, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm trying to implement an authentication flow (user login, log out, autologin etc) in Flutter using AWS Amplify and there is something I can't fixed. I like to do this as clean as possible, so I'm not using third-party packages apart from the AWS ones and Provider for state management.
Autologin is the thing that is not working. I need to hot refresh the app so autologin works. (normally this points towards an state management issue)
I'm not having errors or exceptions of any kind apart from this suspicious output:

```
D/AWSMobileClient(30193): _federatedSignIn: Putting provider and token in store
D/AWSMobileClient(30193): Inspecting user state details
D/AWSMobileClient(30193): hasFederatedToken: false provider: cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2_Fd5bKVAbV
```

Any help is welcome.

main:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Tracks()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Player()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => User()),
        Provider(create: (_) => SearchTracksService()),
        Provider(create: (_) => AuthenticationServices()),
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          Commands.init(context);
          AuthenticationCommands().getCurrentUser();
          //AuthenticationCommands().fetchSession();
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Music Player',
            theme: theme,
            home: Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).isAuthenticated
                ? HomeScreen()
                : AuthenticationScreen(),
            routes: {
              HomeScreen.routeName: (ctx) => HomeScreen(),
              AuthenticationScreen.routeName: (ctx) => AuthenticationScreen(),
              SignUpConfirmationScreen.routeName: (ctx) =>
                  SignUpConfirmationScreen(),
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Future<void> getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      var currentUser = await authenticationServices.getCurrentUser();
      if (currentUser != null) {
        user.id = currentUser.userId;
        user.name = currentUser.username;
        user.email = currentUser.username;
        user.isAuthenticated = true;
        return;
      }

      user.isAuthenticated = false;
    } catch (e) {
      user.isAuthenticated = false;
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

```
Future<AuthUser?> getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      return await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw (e);
    }
  }
```

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class User extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;
  late String _id;
  late String _email;
  late String _name;

  bool get isAuthenticated {
    return _isAuthenticated;
  }

  set isAuthenticated(bool isAuthenticated) {
    _isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get name {
    return _name;
  }

  set name(String name) {
    _name = name;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get id {
    return _id;
  }

  set id(String id) {
    _id = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get email {
    return _email;
  }

  set email(String email) {
    _email = email;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find out what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the "false provider" error message in the console of my IDE while using the Android simulator to run an Amplify/Flutter app.

For me, the user does not get signed in at all when I see those errors in the console - and I think that those two issues are related.

So I opened an issue with the repository regarding this here, you may want to watch it because it may answer this SO issue you've raised: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/1204